# How to run mongodb (extracted from tar.gz) as service in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

For some reason in my area, I'm unable to download and install mongodb normally using `apt-get` from terminal. So I downloaded the `.tar.gz` version from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

I can start it's `mongod` program. But I want to install mongod as a service that runs at startup in my Ubuntu 14.04. How to do this correctly ?
I tried some init.d script provided by this : https://ewan.im/15/mongodb-initd-script

The only problem is: in 14.04, they removed the `chkconfig` . My experiment to install chkconfig ended up with

```
Package chkconfig is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'chkconfig' has no installation candidate
```

edit: I tried https://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu with no luck either.

I expect that I should use `upstart` or `systemd`. Can anyone have example or maybe another solution?

Comment: Did you try this alternative to chkconfig http://askubuntu.com/questions/221293/why-is-chkconfig-no-longer-available-in-ubuntu

Comment: nope, been tried this: sudo sysv-rc-conf mongod on,  still error at connection but if i execute my mongod directly, it runs!

Comment: I cant help for starting mongodb as a service it's up to your personnal configuration but I can make an init.d  script to start and close your mongod at a specific runlevel if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround for starting mongodb as a "service" in init.d :

```
#!/bin/sh
#title         :mongod
#author        :Bertrand Martel
#date          :15/08/2015
#description   :start/stop/restart mongod
#########################################
### install   :  cp mongod /etc/init.d/
#                update-rc.d mongod defaults
### uninstall :  update-rc.d -f mongodb remove

PATH_TO_MONGO=/usr/bin/mongod

#file containing all mongodb pid
PID_FILE=/tmp/mongodb.pid

case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Starting mongodb service..."

        COMMAND_TO_RUN=`start-stop-daemon -S -b -m -p $PID_FILE -x $PATH_TO_MONGO& :`
        setsid sh -c $COMMAND_TO_RUN> /dev/null 2>&1 < /dev/null

        echo -e "\E[31;33m[ OK ]\E[0m"
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stopping mongodb service..."

        start-stop-daemon -K -q -p $PID_FILE

        echo -e "\E[31;33m[ OK ]\E[0m"
        ;;
    restart|reload)
        "$0" stop
        "$0" start
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

For install :

```
cp mongod /etc/init.d/

update-rc.d mongod defaults
```

For uninstall :

```
update-rc.d -f mongodb remove
```

starting :

```
/etc/init.d/mongod start
```

stopping :

```
/etc/init.d/mongod stop
```

restarting :

```
/etc/init.d/mongod restart
```

mongod is automatically launching at boot now.

gist : https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/a3865fa441248f23d51e

Comment: Thank you! I'm able to start `mongod` service using that init.d script above. But there is something that I confused. Line `cp mongod /etc/init.d/` means that the mongod executable itself has to be copied to `/etc/init.d` folder. What for ? I just start my service after installed copied that script into init.d folder using `sudo service mongod start` where `mongod` is a script file above that I copied into init.d folder

Comment: And one more thing I really want to ask, is that script above "universal" ? I mean, does it applied to all range of linux (SUSE, Debian, etc) or just for Ubuntu system ?

Comment: This script will work on System V based distribution which are the most common Linux system. System V will store scripts in rcX.d directory wherease BSD system will store that in /etc/rc.d. init.d scripts are the old way of doing, and so service allows a transition between upstart script and init.d script. upstart is mean to be retrocompatible with init.d. @denny For your fist question I didnt copy the executable of mongod in init.d folder but the startup script I put above. I named the script mongod

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this on Debian 8, I added these LSB tags near the top to get it working:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          mongod
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $named
# Should-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: MongoDB init script
# Description:       MongoDB
### END INIT INFO
```

also, change the first line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```